# Query Builder in Laravel (GROUP BY)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-query-builder

```
$bo_facilities = DB::select('SELECT 
                a.bo_facility_code,
                a.bo_facility_groupcode,
                a.bo_number,
                a.bo_indYesOrNo,
                a.bo_indLogic,
                b.bo_content_facility_description
                FROM bo_facilities AS a 
                RIGHT JOIN bo_content_facilities AS b
                ON b.bo_content_facility_code = a.bo_facility_code AND b.bo_content_facility_facilityGroupCode = a.bo_facility_groupcode

                WHERE a.bo_hotel_code =  "'.$hotel['code'].'"  GROUP BY b.bo_content_facility_description');
```

Error message:

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
'philex.main.a.bo_facility_code' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: 

SELECT a.bo_facility_code,
       a.bo_facility_groupcode,
       a.bo_number,
       a.bo_indyesorno,
       a.bo_indlogic,
       b.bo_content_facility_description
FROM   bo_facilities AS a
       right join bo_content_facilities AS b
               ON b.bo_content_facility_code = a.bo_facility_code
                  AND b.bo_content_facility_facilitygroupcode =
                      a.bo_facility_groupcode
WHERE  a.bo_hotel_code = "'.$hotel['code'].'"
GROUP  BY b.bo_content_facility_description 

)",
```

I was getting this error because of the GROUP BY method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) in mysql.

If you group your results by `b.bo_content_facility_description` the others fields in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY` should be aggregated with a function like `SUM`, `COUNT`, etc.

Grouping by that single field without any arregation on the other fields is meaningful, because you are not specifying how to combine the other fields to get the single record for the grouped field.

I suggest you to clear your head about what results you expect.

Comment: i tried to run that query into mysql it was successfully run.

Comment: If you have the parameter strict = false, every not aggregated field will be considered as if it is listed into the group by fields, but what do you want to do? Group by every field? That is equivalent to use a distinct statement